# Change Fetch URL from event listener?

Tags: javascript, events, fetch-api

I'm trying to change a global variable from inside a click event listener. However the variable fails to change once button is clicked. The objective here is to change a URL for a fetch request.

```
// Default URL
var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&Apikey123';
var req = new Request(url);

// Event Listener - Change URL
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=cnn&apiKey=Apikey123';
  var req = new Request(url);
  sendRequest();
})

// Fetch Data from API
function sendRequest() {
  fetch(req)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => {
      const container = document.getElementsByClassName('post-container')[0];

      for(i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
        // Create post elements
        const post = document.createElement('div');
        const postHeader = document.createElement('div');
        const postBody = document.createElement('div');

        // Set ID
        post.id = 'post';
        postHeader.id = 'post-header';
        postBody.id = 'post-body';

        // Append Elements
        container.appendChild(post);
        post.appendChild(postHeader);
        post.appendChild(postBody);

        // Post title data from array into div
        let article = r.articles[i];
        let title = article.title;
        let content = article.description;
        postHeader.innerHTML = title;
        postBody.innerHTML = content;
      }
      console.log(container);
    });
  }
  sendRequest();
```

Comment: Get rid of the `var` in `var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=cnn&apiKey=Apikey123';`

Comment: All the answer are good ones, is good practice to know. Variable declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any code is executed. The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global. If you re-declare a JavaScript variable, it will not lose its value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem:

```
...
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=cnn&apiKey=Apikey123';
      // Don't use var, becouse it's variable have scope in current function
      // var req = new Request(url);
      req = new Request(url);
      sendRequest();
    })
...
```

But better send param to `sendRequest`:

```
...
    // Event Listener - Change URL
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=cnn&apiKey=Apikey123';
      var req = new Request(url);
      sendRequest(req); // <--- set param
    })

    // Fetch Data from API
    function sendRequest(req) { // <--- get param
      ...
    });
...
```

Answer (score 1):

### Remove the var from inside the Event Listener

```
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() 
{
  url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=cnn&apiKey=Apikey123';
  var req = new Request(url);
  sendRequest();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you are declaring the `var url` twice , and `var req` twice
the first one at the begining of your code and the second one in your event listner ,

try this

```
var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&Apikey123';
var req = new Request(url);

// Event Listener - Change URL
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
 url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=cnn&apiKey=Apikey123';
   req = new Request(url);
  sendRequest();
})

// Fetch Data from API
function sendRequest() {
  fetch(req)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => {
      const container = document.getElementsByClassName('post-container')[0];

      for(i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
        // Create post elements
        const post = document.createElement('div');
        const postHeader = document.createElement('div');
        const postBody = document.createElement('div');

        // Set ID
        post.id = 'post';
        postHeader.id = 'post-header';
        postBody.id = 'post-body';

        // Append Elements
        container.appendChild(post);
        post.appendChild(postHeader);
        post.appendChild(postBody);

        // Post title data from array into div
        let article = r.articles[i];
        let title = article.title;
        let content = article.description;
        postHeader.innerHTML = title;
        postBody.innerHTML = content;
      }
      console.log(container);
    });
  }
  sendRequest();
```